# excute setInterval immediately on first load

Tags: javascript

I'm using setInterval in a function to load a php file every 10 seconds. When the page loads it's not immediately loading the php file the very first time then loading it every 10 seconds thereafter.

```
<script>
setInterval(function(){
          $('#loadthis').load('loadthis.php');
 },10000);
</script>
```

Comment: That's the normal behavior of `setInterval`... Just add `$('#loadthis').load('loadthis.php');` before your `setInterval` call. That's it.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing thanks.

Comment: No problem. ;) Just look at the documentation next time (`Mozilla Developer Network` for example)

Answer (score 0):

That's the normal behavior of setInterval... Just add $('#loadthis').load('loadthis.php'); before your setInterval call. That's it. – Seblor 1 min ago

Comment: Please do not post an answer that is a copy of a comment. Instead delete the answer AND the question since it is not worth keeping for the future

Comment: Thanks to your flagging I can't delete it.